# Query with filter in Spark-SQL forms shuffle boundaries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am loading data into dataframe and then converting to RDD to do some rdd operations. I am loading 17 million records with executor-memory as 3gb ,number of executors and executors cores as 2.

```
DataFrame df = hiveContext.sql("select * from table");
RDD<Row> rddTest = df.rdd();

//explained the flow in a simple way
rddTest.keyBy().cogroup().flatmap().createDataframe().saveAsTable()
```

This conversion takes alot of time and does a shuffle write too. What can I do to improve this?

UPDATE:
[image: rdd forms a different stage boundary]

[image: rdd() does a shuffle operation]

UPDATE 2: rdd() creates 2 stages
[image: rdd() First Stage]

[image: rdd() Second Stage]

UPDATE:

> In my sql query i have a filter condition , which is I guess
>   triggering shuffle (tungestonexchange)

. Is it the right behaviour? I have removed the order by clause.

UPDATE:

The filter expression will cause shuffle and thus a different stage . Now because of this , it becomes memory intensive procedure.

Comment: It does a shuffle write? Where? Since Spark only evaluates on actions, the code you have provided is not evaluated and hence not causing a shuffle write. What action are you calling? Please provide the code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is your worker memory and no of workers assigned for your queue in the cluster and whats the size of data?  Based on the details we can change the executor memory and no of executors and cores

Comment: @RajatMishra I have specified that information in the question

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram my sql query is actually that only with a where clause at max

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt i will update the whole flow in the question, i am doing some operations on RDD and then finally converting back to dataframe and then doing saveAsTable. The call to rdd() makes a different stage and does shuffle (will update with snapshot)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt please check the snapshots

Comment: @AviralKumar following link can help you in deciding the parameters for your spark job \http://c2fo.io/c2fo/spark/aws/emr/2016/07/06/apache-spark-config-cheatsheet/

Comment: thanks Rajat , but I am trying to make my job run with minimum resources. I will try to increase the memory and container allocation once I have absolutely no way left.

Comment: @AviralKumar it's not the conversion to `rdd` that takes time or causes the shuffle - it's the `cogroup` you call after. Note that the Spark UI shows the names of functions at the different stage boundaries - _not_ the names of the functions that causes shuffles. You can look into the DAG of the individual stages to see what part of your code is part of that stage.

Comment: Yes @glenn I have the DAG for the conversion happening. I will update with the screenshot

Comment: @glenn I have updated the question. The DAG attached is for rdd conversion

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I was doing an order by also in my query in few cases which I removed. Then also rdd() causes two stages to be formed and does shuffle write.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I have a doubt. Why is tungestonexchange happening for a query with filter? Filter expression does shuffling?

Comment: TungstenExchange is happening because of the `sort` - not because of the `filter`. It's a little difficult to explain to you which part of your program is causing the shuffles, when you are not providing the full code. However, functions like `join`, `repartition`, `groupBy`, `reduceByKey`, `sort` etc. causes shuffles, while functions like `map` and `filter` do not. Spark group operations in stages based on the shuffle operations and a stage thus never contains more than one shuffle operation. It may however contain any number of `filter` or `map` operations.

Comment: So I have removed sort and filter from the query and still tungeston exchange is happening. The code that i am trying to discuss here is present in the question. The fact shuffle is happening at the rdd() stage is what I am worried about. The other functions like keyby and cougroup are present in other stage and that stage has still not executed